# Oracle SQL Query to get the first 20 instances of a value in a column

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have a database 'Store' that lists, among other information, all customer names and the time which they came into a store, and I want to get one query that will generate all the rows displaying the last 20 times each customer visited the store, anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected output

Comment: please read this. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , we are not genies, what have you tried and please post some sample data, table ddl's, and expected output. Otherwise we are simply shooting fish in barrel.

Comment: This is a trivial query to write, but it is more challenging because you need to provide additional information. Please provide the schema of your table (table name, column name, data types, etc).

Answer (score 0):

I would start with

```
SELECT * FROM
( SELECT 
    customer_name, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY store ORDER BY entry_time DESC) rn
  FROM my_table )
WHERE rn <= 20;
```

Answer (score 0):

it is realy difficult to answer your question with only this information.

please note structure of your tables or something..

in generally -

let's say that your table is "customers" 
and every customer has unique "cust_id". 
"visit_time" will be the time of each record that customer get into a store.

```
select * 
from (
select row_number () over (partition by c.cust_id order by c.visit_time desc) rw
from customers c) inn
where inn.rw <= 20;
```